# External authentication with IdentityServer for mobile clients

Tags: identityserver4

I have IdentityServer4 configured for my JS clients , and I am using ResourceOwner flow for getting access_token and authenticate the user. This flow can work for both JS clients and mobile apps.

Now I want to authenticate my native mobile app clients with external providers like Facebook, Twitter etc using my IdentityServer4.

I have run the samples for IdentityServer4 using External Providers but I want to authenticate my mobile app users from native apps (android , ios) , please give me suggestion that how can I achieve that? I know that it is not possible without redirects , this is OK.

Comment: You need to use a browser from the mobile app. See these samples: https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples

Comment: @BrockAllen That is not what we want. If we use a browser, the user has to enter username and password. Since they have already login in the native app it is better if we can use that. Is there any way to generate access token using the token that provides by facebook. If it is, we can authenticate the user in the mobile app using native way. get facebook token. Submit that token to IdentityServer gets an access token.

Comment: I am doing the exact same thing in my id server implementation

Comment: Any thoughts on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60187173/oidc-register-auto-login-flow-for-mobile-apps

Comment: @muhammadwaqas Can you please tell me how you managed to do this?